# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and trying to have an ajax query which is called every 5 seconds and updates some content.

Using the code below, I get the following error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
```

The line the error is on is line 3 of jquery.min.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function getData()
      {
        $.getJSON('/ajax/pull', function(data){
          console.log(data.items);

          $("span").each(data.items, function(items){
            console.log(items);
            if($(this).attr('id') in items)
            {
                console.log('here');
            }
          });

        });
      }
      window.setInterval(function() { getData(); } , 5000);
  });
```

I've looked through the other questions which have the same problem, but trying those fixes has no affect on my problem.

Comment: Just added those two semicolons (and updated the code here) but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) takes only 1 argument which is a function not an array.

Comment: Gah! I can't *believe* I overlooked that... +1! Clearly a confusion between [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), then.

Comment: Actually there is an alternate syntax that accepts arrays, but even then it wouldn't have worked here anyway. `$.each(array, function(i, v){})`